# Alignement sequence to existing profile

Tags: bioinformatics, biojava

I would like to ask if there is possible using biojava add sequence to exiting profile alignement ? I mean I would like to keep my existing profile stable. If i add new sequence to align, if there  appear a gap in profile it will be  through whole column - that what I want to get.

Comment: you should ask https://www.biostars.org/

Comment: which profile format are you referring to?  I know of several

Comment: what do you mean "profile format"? I use biojava to make aligment (to be more accurate MSA using getMultipleSequenceAlignment() method. I receive profile and now I want to align profile with sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "MAFFT --add" web-server at https://mafft.cbrc.jp/alignment/server/add.html